# Using file path enable file preview(thumbnail) in reactjs

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, antd

I need to display the first page of the file as a thumbnail using **reactjs** in each of the Card element obtained from ANTD UI framework as show below:

```
<Card>
    <a href={file.path}></a>
</Card>
```

NOTE:

- I will get the file path from the python/flask server.
- File formats = ["pptx", "txt", "docx", "bdf", "mud", "pdf","xlsx","msg","zip","eml"]

Any leads/links will be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some extent [react-file-viewer][1] npm package does the job. Using the following syntax:

```
import FileViewer from 'react-file-viewer';
......
<FileViewer
      fileType='xlsx'
      filePath='http://localhost:8000/static/test.xlsx'
      onError={this.onError}
/>
```

NOTE: CORS policy should be enabled if the file is present in a different domain.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer